# Looping through JSON in php is slowing down my page loading

Tags: php, json, loops

I have a small website [jamesmcnee.co.uk](http://jamesmcnee.co.uk) and the page loading times of it are quite high. It can take as long as 8 - 12s to load a page. I think that it is something to do with the PHP I have created to interact with the Steam API. I have these files:

1. SteamWidget.php:

   ```
   $api = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=". $key ."&steamids=76561198014955377&format=json";
   $json = file_get_contents($api);
   $schemaProfile = json_decode($json, true);

   $api = "http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=". $key ."&steamid=76561198014955377&format=json";
   $json = file_get_contents($api);
   $schemaGames = json_decode($json, true);

   echo '<div id="sideSteamProfile">';
   echo '<h2>On Steam</h2>';
   echo '<img src="'; echo $schemaProfile['response']['players'][0]['avatarfull']; echo '" alt="Steam Avatar Icon" />';
   echo '<p>Steam Name:<a href="'; echo $schemaProfile['response']['players'][0]['profileurl']; echo '">'; 
   echo $schemaProfile['response']['players'][0]['personaname']; echo '</a></p>';
   if($schemaProfile['response']['players'][0]['personastate'] == "0"){
           echo '<p>Currently: <font color="red">Offline</font></p>';
       }
       else{
           echo '<p>Currently: <font color="green">Online</font></p>';
       }       
   echo '<p>Last Online:'; echo gmdate("d-m-Y  H:i", $schemaProfile['response']['players'][0]['lastlogoff']); echo '</p>';
   echo '<p>Number of Games:'; echo $schemaGames['response']['game_count']; echo '</p>';
   echo '<p>Most Played Game:'; echo getMostPlayed(); echo '</p>';
   echo '<p>Total Hours:'; echo getHoursPlayed(); '</p>';
   echo '</div> <!-- Closes the sideSection div -->'; ?>
   ```

The second one is called MostPlayed.php:

```
<?php 
    include 'ApiKey.php';
    function getMostPlayed()
    {
        $GameWithMostHours = "None";
        $api = "http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=". $key ."&steamid=76561198014955377&format=json";
        $json = file_get_contents($api);
        $schemaGames = json_decode($json, true);

        $NumberOfGames = $schemaGames['response']['game_count'];

        $CurrentlyHighestHours = 0;
        for ($x = 0; $x < $NumberOfGames; $x++){
            $CheckHighest = $schemaGames['response']['games'][$x]['playtime_forever'];
            if ($CheckHighest > $CurrentlyHighestHours){
                $CurrentlyHighestHours = $CheckHighest;
                $GameWithMostHours = $schemaGames['response']['games'][$x]['name'];
            }
        }

        return $GameWithMostHours;
    }

    function getHoursPlayed()
    {
        $api = "http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=". $key ."&steamid=76561198014955377&format=json";
        $json = file_get_contents($api);
        $schemaGames = json_decode($json, true);

        $NumberOfGames = $schemaGames['response']['game_count'];
        $TotalNumberOfHours = 0;

        for ($x = 0; $x < $NumberOfGames; $x++){
            $TotalNumberOfHours += $schemaGames['response']['games'][$x]['playtime_forever'];
        }

        $TotalNumberOfHours = sprintf("%02dh %02dm", floor($TotalNumberOfHours/60), $TotalNumberOfHours%60);
        return $TotalNumberOfHours;
    }
?>
```

So two reletively simple PHP files, so why the increase in loading speed. As I mentioned I think it has something to do with the for loops I am using but I dont see another way to do this and in another language such as JAVA, these loops would take a fraction of a second. Any advice is appreciated!

Thanks James McNee.

Comment: Are you sure it is the loops? More likely to be the latency for the steampowered api. Try logging the calls and their response time.

Comment: I was thinking about something on steams end but because of the size of the company thought that it wouldn't be that. Anyway how would I go about logging the calls?

Comment: Most people would start by using microtime just before the call and just after the return. You will at least see if the time is negligable or not.

Comment: Yes looks like you was right, it took a whopping 13.099297046661 seconds on my local xampp. So I mean what can I do about this if I still want to keep the widget. Is there a way to load the rest of the page while this element is loading, or a way to speed it up? Thanks for the help diagnosing the problem by the way, its much appreciated.

Comment: Wel yes there is, indeed many ways I am sure. You could load the page and have it make the calls via AJAX, but then you would have to write that looping code in javascript. You could have the page make calls to another script and it would then amke the call and process the data before returning it to the page. If your page loads quickly otherwise then I would go with that.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by your second option as I think I am already doing this, all my pages make called to the SteamWidget.php script. I use includes to do this. How are you suggesting that I do it to speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the page without doing those calls to that API. Have an AJAX call that runs on document ready to a script that gets the data, processes it and returns the html that you want to display.

Comment: Please forgive me for asking so many questions and feel free to stop answering, but I have never before used AJAX and I am relitively new to web development and am used to more desktop based development. If you could, would you please explain to me in a little more detail how I would go about doing this AJAX call, or post some links to relevant material on the subject.

Comment: Google jQuery AJAX and follow a tutorial.

Comment: You sir deserve a big thankyou. Not only did you help me diagnose the issue, but you provided me with a fix and helped me learn a new great feature of web design, so for that thankyou. With about 6 lines of AJAX I have managed to solve my slow loading time issues. The div still takes about 12 seconds to actually appear, but unfortunatly I cannot make steams API load faster. Anyway, thanks a bunch!